# How to index a specific value for a Firebase Node

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Below is a simplistic version of the fire base database:

```
Players {
 {
name: 'Messi',
goals: 90,
assists:2
id: 1
},
{
name: 'Beckham',
assists: 14,
goals: 22
id: 2
},
{
name: 'Rooney',
goals: 10,
assistst: 3
id: 3
},
{
name: 'Neymar',
goals: 14,
assists: 1
id: 4
}
}
```

The players are brought into the scope as such:

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("players");
  var ref3 = firebase.database().ref("users").child(uid).child("total");

  $scope.players = $firebaseArray(ref);
  $scope.selection = $firebaseArray(ref3);
```

Is there a way to index the player ids so that the following code will produce the selected players:

`firebase.database().ref("players").orderByChild("id").equalTo($scope.selection);`

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, which makes it hard to answer. Please provide a snippet of your actual JSON. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data and limit to a set number of results.  Check out the Limit Queries section in the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

```
var ref = db.ref("dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("goals").limitToLast(2).on("child_added",
```

Comment: thanks. But what I am trying to achieve is to index in such a way that  it is only the numbers in the selection array of "ref3" that tally with the player ids in the players array or "ref" that are displayed.